# AuthKey in header

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, authentication

So my client needs a REST API using PHP that provides output as per the conditions on the URL parameters

So now there are three URL's basically which is currently needed and they are done.

so they are

```
localhost/newapi/client/<AuthKey> - for authorizing

localhost/newapi/client/<clientid>/categories/ - to get all the categories

localhost/newapi/client/<clientid>/categories/<categoryid> - to get all items in a category
```

used .htaccess for fancy URL

So now he requested that AuthKey need to be added to HTTP header not the URL. So the AuthKey must be passed as header and the rest as URL parameters

So my question is how this can be done. and how to retrieve the AuthKey from the request?

Any tutorials or comments regarding this question is welcome

Comment: That's not a common way to do this. Better to include authentication with every request, or post to the authentication endpoint then set up a session once authorised

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can tell the client when he request your api he add a header as below:

AuthKey: your-api-auth-key
or
Token: your-api-token

and then in your php code make

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$token = $headers['Token'] or ['AuthKey'];
```

then you check if the key in database and then process your code

Note:
your client can add Header with PHP cURL

```
curl_setopt($curl-handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, array(
'Token' => 'client-auth-token', //or
'AuthKey' => 'client-auth-token'
));
```

Comment: Thnx for response actually the API is for an iPhone APP

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to connect with rest in php

```
$url = 'localhost/newapi/client/';
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"."Authorization: Basic ".<authkey>."\r\n",
            'content' => $data,
            'timeout' => 60
            )
        );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context, -1, 40000);

    return $result;
```

Comment: Thnx for this code... now i know how to set and call the api using headers in php

Comment: If need any help, feel free to ask.